# How to feed an image slider from a flat JSON file by Handlebars template?

Tags: json, jquery, handlebars.js, flexslider

I want to feed an image slider (flexslider) from a flat JSON file by Handlebars template. for that I tried this.

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    dataType : 'json',
    async: false,
    url: window.location.href + "JSON/carousel-data.json",
    success : function(data) {
        console.log(data); 
        var src = document.getElementById("sliderTemplate").innerHTML;
        var tmpl = Handlebars.compile(src);
        $('#imageslider').innerHTML = tmpl(data); 
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({animation: "slide"});
    } 
});
```

But slider is not instantiated by this code.
However if I assign the same content of JSON file to a variable in same JS file and pass it to Handlebars template it works fine.

What is the problem with my ajax code?

Comment: Does the `success` handler get called at all? Any errors?

Comment: I found the solution, everything is ok but one line that is  $('#imageslider').innerHTML = tmpl(data);  It should be $('#imageslider').HTML(tmpl(data));

Comment: You can write that up as an answer and accept it (but you might have to wait a day to accept your owner answer), AFAIK an answered question is easier to find than an unanswered one and this information might be useful to someone else.

Comment: Thanks.. I will do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, everything is fine but one line that is

```
$('#imageslider').innerHTML = tmpl(data);
```

It should be

```
$('#imageslider').HTML(tmpl(data));
```

As it follows the jQuery syntex.